# Should We pass function as dependencies in UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

While using `useEffect` in **TypeScript**, failing to pass a function to the dependencies array results in a warning.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    if(isAuthenticated){
        history.push('/dashboard')
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [isAuthenticated]);
```

I am currently using `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` to suppress the warning, but I know this is not recommended.

So, should I pass functions in the `useEffect` dependencies array?

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

I see what you're meaning now. You probably shouldn't put it in the dependency array as when you're logged in you won't be able to move off the dashboard as it will ping you back. This is why the state change should be done imperatively.

---

Based on what you're said, the value should be in the dependency array otherwise it won't re-run when the authentication state changes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) history.push('/dashboard');
}, [isAuthenticated])
```

It's worth noting that this side effect should probably be run imperatively where the authenticated state changes, e.g. in the onFullfilled handler of a login promise.